# Run QDialog object from a static function after QMainWindow is opened

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to open a modal dialog box (to log in) from a static function after the QMainWindow object is opened.

```
class DialogLog : public QDialog {
    DialogLog(QWidget * parent) : QDialog(parent) {
        //some code
        exec();
    }
};

class LogHandler {
    static bool log(QWidget * parent) {
        DialogLog dl(parent);
        //some code
    }
};

class WinMain : public QMainWindow {}

main(..) {
    QApplication app(..);

    WinMain fen;
    fen.show;

    app.exec();
};
```

EDIT : How can i run LogHandler::log() after/at the same time of WinMain ?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a better solution, but here is what you could do : use a [singleshot timer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html#singleShot) that will shot immediatly (i.e. as soon as the event pump will be looping).

The timer will call a slot of, for instance, your `WinMain` class :

```
void main(..) {
    QApplication app(..);

    WinMain fen;
    fen.show;

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &fen, SLOT(login()));
    app.exec();
};
```

In the `login()` slot of `WinMain`you would have your call to `LogHandler::log()` :

```
void WinMain::login() {
   if (!LogHandler::log(this))
      qApp->quit();
}
```